# Extensions for a short exact sequence on Grassmannians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology, grassmannians

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sym{Sym}\DeclareMathOperator\Ext{Ext}$Let us consider a $n$-dimensional complex vector space $V$ and denote by $G(k,n)$ the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $V$. We use the convention that the universal exact sequence on $G(k,n)$ is given by
$$
0 \to S \to V \otimes \mathcal O \to Q \to 0,
$$
with $S,Q$ of rank $k$ and $n-k$ respectively. I want to study the (possible) extensions of the following short exact sequence on $G(k,n)$:
$$\tag{$\star$}
0 \to Q^\vee \otimes S^\vee \to N \to \Sym^2S^\vee \to 0.
$$
More precisely, I'm asking if $N$ has to be $(Q \otimes S)^\vee \oplus \Sym^2 S^\vee$.

In order to attack the problem, I try to compute
$$
\Ext^1(\Sym^2 S^\vee,Q^\vee \otimes S^\vee)=H^1(G(k,n),Q^\vee \otimes S^\vee \otimes \Sym^2 S),
$$
but now I don't have idea on how to compute such a cohomology piece.
Any idea on how to go on?

**Edit 1:** I also know that $N$ fits in another short exact sequence of vector bundles on $G(k,n)$:
$$\tag{$\star\star$}
0 \to N \to S^\vee \otimes (V^\vee \otimes \mathcal O) \to {\bigwedge}^2 S^\vee \to 0
$$
that is $N=\ker \phi$ where $\phi: S^\vee \otimes (V^\vee \otimes \mathcal O) \to {\bigwedge}^2 S^\vee$.

Comment: These are homogeneous vector bundles, so in principle their cohomology is computable — I don't know if this is doable in practice. The standard reference is *Cohomology of vector bundles and syzygies* by Jerzy Weyman (CUP).

Comment: I have computed the weights in general (it is a mess) and in the particular case of $G(2,4)$. There is at least one non dominant weight, in particular the $H^0$ will be zero, but it does not give me information about $H^1$

Comment: You can do this using the Borel-Weil-Bott theorem and a bit of representation theory, as abx suggests. The bundle in question should be decomposable, and you can obtain such a decomposition using the Schurrings package of Macaulay2. After getting a decomposition, you can use BWB to compute the cohomology groups of each factor and take the sum. Have a look at proposition 3.1 here for some similar computations https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.05162.pdf . After doing a few cases for small k,n, you can hopefully try to get a general picture for the decomposition of your bundle.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sym{Sym}$I’ll write the weight of $S^\vee$ as $(0,\ldots,0,-1)$; it might be helpful to think of this bundle as $\bigwedge^{k-1}S \otimes \det(S)^{-1}$. For $\Sym^2(S)$ the weight is $(2,0,\ldots,0)$; both of these are vectors with $k$ entries. By the Pieri rule,

$$S^\vee \otimes \Sym^2(S) \cong S \oplus \mathbb{S}_{(2,0,\dotsc,0,-1)}(S),$$
where $\mathbb{S}$ denotes the Schur functor.

Similarly the weight of $Q^\vee$ is $(0,\dotsc,0,-1)$ (with $n-k$ entries). So we concatenate the weights for each of the two summands:

$$w = (0,\dotsc,0,-1,1,0,\dotsc,0) \text{ and } w'= (0,\dotsc,0,-1,2,0,\dotsc, 0,-1).$$

By Borel–Weil–Bott we add $\rho = (n,n-1,\dotsc,1)$ and count inversions in the resulting word; if there is a repeat, all the cohomology vanishes.

In the first case there is exactly one inversion, so the bundle has nonvanishing $H^1$. After sorting, the resulting weight is

$$\operatorname{sort}(w+\rho)-\rho = \vec{0}.$$
So $H^1$ is one-dimensional (the trivial representation). For the other, $w'+\rho$ has a repeat from the $2$ and the $0$ two steps before it. So all the cohomology vanishes.

Edit: Exception: for the second calculation, if $n-k=1$ then the repeat doesn’t occur. In that case I guess there is one inversion and nonvanishing $H^1$ of weight $(1,0,\dotsc,0,-1)$ which has rank $n^2-1$; it is the kernel of $V \otimes V^\vee \to \mathbb{C}$, i.e. the traceless matrices. Also, if $k=1$ then the second summand simply doesn’t occur at all. I think the calculation above is correct otherwise, that is if $n-k$ and $k$ are both $\geq 2$.

Comment: Can you please add a reference for the vanishing of cohomology of bundles induced from representations with singular weights?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate
$$
H^1(G(k,n),Q^\vee \otimes S^\vee \otimes Sym^2 S)
$$
you can use the Kostant's version of the Bott-Borel-Weil theorem which computes $H^k(G/P, V_\lambda)$ for an associated bundle to a highest weight represetnation $\mathbb{V}_\lambda$. The answer is given in terms of action of certain elements of the Weyl group, which in the case of Grassmannians and $k=1$ shouldn't be too complicated. However, you first have to decompose the inducing representation of your bundle into irreducible pieces, which can become unwieldy in the general case. Nevertheless, decomposition of tensor product is algorithmic, so you can just run the algorithm for several different ranks and see how it behaves.